# Add custom saved params on featherjs

Tags: feathersjs

Im noobs use FeatherJS and I stuck on roles and permissions management in FeatherJS

I have tables contains users, users_role, and roles. Table roles have relationship with two permissions table. I dont save roles to users's table because one user can have more than one role.

[image]

I want to save roles.id into `params.user`, but I don't find the way how to save it. I want it because it's not efficient to query to database if I want to check a permission.

I try using

```js
app.on('login', (authResult: AuthenticationResult, { connection }: Params) => {
    app
      .get('postgresqlClient')
      .select('users_roles.role_id')
      .from('users_roles')
      .where('users_roles.user_id', '=', authResult.user.id)
      .then(function (results) {
        for (const index in results) {
          authResult.user['roles'].push(results[index].role_id)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))

    if (connection) {
      app.channel('anonymous').leave(connection)
      console.log('An user leave anonymous channel')

      app.channel('authenticated').join(connection)
      app.channel('authenticated')
      console.log('An user authenticated and join authenticated channel')
    }
  })
```

But it seems not saved into context.

```json
{
  "accessToken": "jwtinhere",
  "authentication": {
    "strategy": "local",
    "payload": {
      "iat": 1675662745,
      "exp": 1675749145,
      "aud": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "sub": "843438ee-69cb-493f-8812-71f0c7462f2f",
      "jti": "dbd0641c-65b2-413c-ae80-52ba5f9c4e89"
    }
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "843438ee-69cb-493f-8812-71f0c7462f2f",
    "full_name": "Super Admin",
    "email": "admin@local.local",
    "created_at": "2023-01-31T15:08:06.141Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-01-31T15:08:06.141Z"
  }
}
```

I want to my roles saved on context, so the result after successfully authentication is

```json
{
  "accessToken": "jwtinhere",
  "authentication": {
    "strategy": "local",
    "payload": {
      "iat": 1675662745,
      "exp": 1675749145,
      "aud": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "sub": "843438ee-69cb-493f-8812-71f0c7462f2f",
      "jti": "dbd0641c-65b2-413c-ae80-52ba5f9c4e89"
    }
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "843438ee-69cb-493f-8812-71f0c7462f2f",
    "full_name": "Super Admin",
    "email": "admin@local.local",
    "created_at": "2023-01-31T15:08:06.141Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-01-31T15:08:06.141Z",
    "role": [0,1] // Added Role
  }
}
```

And I only call `context.params.user.role` in hook if want to check the user roles. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could include the relation on the entityService (probably the users-service) get method. The authentication service calls the entityService's get method when creating the authentication. If you only need the role.id's, you could map it in the after hooks user the alterItems-hook.

For example create a generic hook 'includeRelation' and call it the before get hook:

**include-relation.hook.ts**

```
export function includeRelation(tableName: string, asKey?: string, raw = false) {
  return async (context: HookContext) => {
    checkContext(context, 'before', ['find', 'get']);

    context.params.sequelize = {
      include: {
        model: context.app.get('sequelizeClient').models[tableName],
        as:
          asKey ??
          // convert snake case (table_name) to camel case (tableName)
          tableName
            .split('_')
            .map((name, index) => (index > 0 ? name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) : name))
            .join(''),
      },
      raw,
      nest: true,
    };

    return context;
  };
}
```

**user.hooks.ts**

```
export const usersHooks: HooksObject = {
  before: {
    get: [includeRelation('users_roles', 'usersRoles', true)],
  },
};
```

Check `node_modules/@feathersjs/authentication/src/jwt.ts` to see how it works.